# std::end and std::begin in a function (C++)

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I tried to get the length of the string array, and I've done it in the main function and it worked. Afterwards I needed to do so in a function, but it doesn't identifies the functions with error:

> IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "begin" matches the argument list

code:

```
void fun(string arr[])
{
    cout << end(arr) - begin(arr);
}

void main()
{
    string arr[] = {"This is a single string"};
    fun(arr);
}
```

also for the end.

So I added the pointer symbol '*' and the error disappeared, but it returns me the length of the first item in the array.

Why do I get this error? How to fix it?

Comment: If you are expecting an array of strings use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Where did you add a '*'? `void fun(string arr[]);` is exactly the same as `void fun(string* arr);`, btw.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying

Comment: Side note:  `void main()` is invalid.  `main` *must* return an *int*

Comment: @JohnDibling void is ok

Comment: No, its not. The standard requires that main return an int

Comment: As already mentioned, one way to avoid array decay is to pass the array as reference. One easy to miss key factor is to provide the array size in the parameter like: `void fun(string (&arr)[10])`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this via

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<size_t N>
void fun(std::string (&arr)[N])
{
    std::cout << std::end(arr) - std::begin(arr);
}

int main (void)
{
    std::string arr[] = {"This is a single string"};
    fun(arr);
}
```

But in your example the array is decaying into a pointer so you can't call `sizeof`, `begin` or `end`.

Comment: +1? That's type system abuse, the conventional way of passing vanilla  arrays around is as (begin, length) or (begin, end).

Comment: That's at least debatable. I don't think that passing an array by reference is type system abuse. Furthermore, I think one should stick to `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of "vanilla arrays" in terms of modern C++ if possible. But that's not the question.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Indeed, with this approach, you can just use `N`, but OP's approach was given as an answer from his previous question, but no one told him it wouldn't work as soon as you passed it to a function.

Comment: @remyabel The answer of juanchopanza to the previous question actually covers passing a reference to the array into a function correctly. So there was no need to tell him that it won't work when passed to a function since that's what it does: it works as intended.

Comment: @Kos:  Can't be done with string literals, for instance.  There is value to this idiom.  I +1'ed an said "There we go" because this precisely answers the question as asked, without changing the conditions of the question, after several other people's failed attempts.  Your answer would be equally valid in my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not really working on an array of string... You're working with a pointer on a `std::string`, because `std::string arr[]` decays to `std::string*`.

So what it means is just `std::end()` and `std::begin()` don't work for pointers.

The workaround I prefer is to use `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>` or to retrieve begin end before calling the function:

```
template <typename iterator>
void fun(iterator begin, iterator end)
{
    std::cout << end - begin; 
}

int main()
{
    std::string arr[] = {"This is a single string"};
    fun(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
    return 0;
}
```

I do not like having the size hardcoded in a parameter like suggested in another answer, but it is a matter of personal taste.

Comment: This answer changes the conditions of the question.  OP was using an array -- an array with 1 element.

Comment: I want array of strings, not array of a string

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I appreciate the `vector` suggestion, but there is another workaround that uses an array and doesn't rely on hardcoding the dimensions of the array.